# How to disable session resumption with OpenSSL s_server

Tags: openssl, tls1.2

I am trying to check for session-re-negotiation. 
I am using OpenSSL as a reference server, and I am doing a TLS handshake and capture session data (and Session ID.)
Then I re-establishing the connection providing same saved session, and, as expected OpenSSL server resumes the session, providing me with the same session id.
But I can not make server to reject the resumption request and force re-negotiation, establishing new session ID and new shared secret
I always get

```
Reused session-id
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
```

This is what i get:

```
root@test:~# openssl s_server -port 443 -cert leaf1.crt -key leaf1.key -tls1_2 -no_ticket -no_resumption_on_reneg
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
-----BEGIN SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
MHoCAQECAgMDBALMqAQg2CsxwQa4O8uwlBZIdQsmF4LiAGqiV4iHIafx1cG2LJ0E
MMfN2I0yVW26vrUketgIUptqVE2Tzfmg/Mn7RnO3htgfCyJoI4vwyY4NzfIwz5Aa
O6EGAgReq9fTogQCAhwgpAYEBAEAAACtAwIBAQ==
-----END SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
Shared ciphers:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA
Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1
Shared Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1
Supported Elliptic Curve Point Formats: uncompressed
Supported Elliptic Groups: X25519:X448:P-384:P-256:P-521:0x0100:0x0101:0x0102:0x0103:0x0104
Shared Elliptic groups: X25519:X448:P-384:P-256:P-521
---
No server certificate CA names sent
CIPHER is ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
ERROR
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
-----BEGIN SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
MHoCAQECAgMDBALMqAQg2CsxwQa4O8uwlBZIdQsmF4LiAGqiV4iHIafx1cG2LJ0E
MMfN2I0yVW26vrUketgIUptqVE2Tzfmg/Mn7RnO3htgfCyJoI4vwyY4NzfIwz5Aa
O6EGAgReq9fTogQCAhwgpAYEBAEAAACtAwIBAQ==
-----END SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
Shared ciphers:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA
Supported Elliptic Curve Point Formats: uncompressed
Supported Elliptic Groups: X25519:X448:P-384:P-256:P-521:0x0100:0x0101:0x0102:0x0103:0x0104
Shared Elliptic groups: X25519:X448:P-384:P-256:P-521
---
No server certificate CA names sent
CIPHER is ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Reused session-id
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
ERROR
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

Comment: try diasbling RFC4507 support in whatever client you use as in s_client

Comment: Whole Idea is no reject it on the server.

Comment: I see. It has already been answered. I will add: sometimes the documentation for openssl is missing details such as these flags. I search for RFC*** in the codebase to figure out. Or ask on this site. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two different concepts: resumption and renegotiation.

Resumption refers to starting a new connection based on the session details from a previous connection.

Renegotiation refers to starting a second or subsequent handshake on an *existing* SSL/TLS connection.

You can cause s_server to refuse to resume sessions like this:

```
openssl s_server -port 443 -cert leaf1.crt -key leaf1.key -no_ticket -no_cache
```

You can cause s_server to refuse renegotiation requests like this (only from OpenSSL 1.1.1 and above):

```
openssl s_server -port 443 -cert leaf1.crt -key leaf1.key -no_renegotiation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did the trick. I knew this can be done somehow but manual pages do not say anything about -no_cache, so i was piling up all keys that might help. P.S. the poor quality of openssl docs just kills me, for such a universal tool one might expect different.

Comment: I added the missing documentation and a number of other missing s_server option docs: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/11712